# How can I group items together, such as a card, inside Jetpack Compose LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

[Grouped result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3bg2.png)

I am trying to group items like I have in my picture above where you have a header, then a grouping, such as a card, and inside the card, a list of items. I cannot figure out a way to achieve this using LazyColumn for the items inside the card. Currently, I have a list with 100+ items in a group and they are not being loaded lazily.

```
LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
) {
    items(rows, key = { it.getUniqueId() }) {
        HeaderWithRows(it.title, it.innerRows) {
            Text(it.text)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HeaderWithRows(
    title: String?,
    rows: List<AbstractRow>,
    itemRow: @Composable (AbstractRow) -> Unit,
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)) {
        Header(
            title = title,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
        )
        Card {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 8.dp)) {
                rows.forEach {
                    itemRow(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't embed a LazyColumn inside another LazyColumn and I've tried to use the LazyListScope from the parent inside the loop and that doesn't work either.

Comment: As seen in the preview your items are limited so you must use ```Column``` with ```verticleScroll```

Comment: This is just an example, I have a screen that will have 100+ items

Comment: Then you have to use ```LazyColumn```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your groups are big and you want lazily load individual group items, each group item has to be inside its own `item {}`, there's no other way. This means you can't put them inside one `Card` composable - you will have to create special background for top, middle and bottom row, so that it looks like a Card when you put them together.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion to create special background helped me

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by [@JanBína](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801938/jan-b%C3%ADna), I have customized the shape of each Item card to get it look like all items are in a card while also displaying a header above the card the code looks something like this

```
@Composable
fun TransactionItem(
    transaction: Transaction,
    index: Int = 0,
    totalSize: Int = 1,
    onTransactionClicked: (Transaction) -> Unit
) {
    val transactionDateTime = Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(transaction.date).toLocalDateTime(
        TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
    )
    var cardMod = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
        .padding(bottom = if (index == totalSize - 1) 5.dp else 0.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)

    cardMod = if (totalSize == 1) {
        cardMod.padding(vertical = 5.dp)
    } else when (index) {
        0 -> cardMod.padding(top = 5.dp)
        totalSize - 1 -> cardMod.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
        else -> cardMod.padding(vertical = 0.dp)
    }

    ElevatedCard(
        onClick = {
            onTransactionClicked(transaction)
        },
        modifier = cardMod,
        shape = when (totalSize) {
            1 -> RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
            else -> when (index) {
                0 -> RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 15.dp, topEnd = 15.dp)
                totalSize - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 15.dp, bottomEnd = 15.dp)
                else -> RoundedCornerShape(0)
            }
        }
    ) {
       ///Item Content goes here
    }
}
```

Please do suggest me if any better solution is available the final result looks [image: like this]

Comment: Looks good. Only thing - the code you have in the if-else doesn't do anything. Modifier is immutable, so when you call `cardMod.padding(vertical = 5.dp)`, it doesn't change the `cardMod`, it creates new modifier - you have to use the returned value.

Comment: I get what you were saying, what if I return the value from if else and use it? will it be better?

Comment: I have changed the code so that I am reassigning modifier back to cardMod using if-else, can you please suggest any changes which can improve it's performance I don't know why but after the above changes app is not as smooth as it used to be, Particularly in low-end devices, is that because of the cards or something else

Comment: Yeah, the modifier is ok now. Otherwise, I don't see anything that might cause issues you're talking about...